# Much more dramatically

Tags: grammar, word-choice

Does it sound natural to native speakers?
"It could have ended much more sadly."
Should I say instead: "It could have ended much more dramatically."

Comment: ***sadly*** and ***dramatically*** have completely different meanings. Use the one that means what you want to say.

Answer (score 2):

> It could have ended much more sadly.

That is perfectly natural.

> It could have ended much more dramatically.

That does not mean the same thing.